# webpy template multiple inheritance, possible?

Tags: templates, inheritance, web.py

I want to divide index page into small stand alone .html parts like:

up_bar.html:
`<p><center>
    <h1>home</h1>
    Menu: <a href="/">home</a> <a href="add">add</a> <a href="/import">import</a>`

down_bar.html:
`<a href="/path/.."/>`
and so on.
Now, to build a new page is it possible to embed those pieces into other page using **default** webpy templator?

Maybe something like that?:
in admin.html:
`$def with(some_parameters):`
`<title>Admin panel</title>`
`$include('side_bar.html')`
`... body stuff ...`
`$include('down_bar.html')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: 
http://groups.google.com/group/webpy/msg/ea6da02dfb9eedc4?dmode=source

Some explanation will be great.

Answer (score 1):

A basic but good introduction to template inheritance can be found here: http://webpy.org/cookbook/layout_template

Answer (score 0):

I did this to my code

```
def GET(self,*args):
    param= {'name':'jackie'}
    view = web.template.frender("views/someview.html")
    content = view(**param)
    layout = web.template.frender("views/index.html")
    return layout(content=content)
```

now you just insert `$:content` in `index.html`